# Leave out search results older than two years by default

Tags: google-search

One thing I don't like about Google Search is that it often includes results that are very very old. Is there a way to permanently turn off old results, like block all results older than two years? If I ever wanted to search for older results too, mind you this is rare, there would be a feature for temporarily turning them on again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can *permanently* block older results but you can certainly limit the results to whatever date range you want.

Click "Search tools" in the bar at the top of the results, then select what you want.  Default is "Any time".

[image: Google search tools to limit date range for results]

Comment: As close as it gets maybe. A save feature there would be perfect. Maybe _someone_ can make a browser add-on in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with Opera (or another browser that allows you to specify/edit search engine URLs). Simply put, you just need to **add "&as_qdr=y2" (without quotes) to the URL.**

Detailed instructions for Opera:

1. Click the Opera button -> Settings -> Preferences
2. Click Search tab
3. Double-click Google
4. Click Details >>
5. Add "&as_qdr=y2" (without quotes) to the end of the Address field
6. Click OK twice and you're done

Anytime you search from anywhere in Opera, you'll only see results from the last 2 years.

[image: Restricting Google results to prior 2 years with Opera]